# the function of used to in sentences

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence I am confused about the function of **used to** being used with a verb to describe an action that occurred and finished in the past.

Sentence: **I used to drink coffee every day.**

Question: Is **used** functioning as a verb here with **to drink** as its full infinitive object?

The word **used** is classified in the dictionary as an adjective, but another web site states that **used+to+verb** act together as a verb phrase.

Thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the verb is just "used". What follows it is a _to_ infinitival clause. There is an adjective  form as in "used car", but that's something else altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**used to do something**](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_used-to-do.htm) is an expression or a verb phrase as your website correctly states (some other dictionaries define is as a modal verb). When you say that you used to do something, it means that you were doing something in the past on a more or less regular basis, but are no longer in the habit of doing it.

Example #1:

> When I was younger, I **used to smoke** a lot. Now that I'm older, I only smoke a few cigarettes a day.

Example #2:

> When I lived in New York, I **used to visit** Manhattan every weekend.

[**used**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/used), on the other hand, is an adjective. If something has been used, it means that it has been, well, literally used. A good example would be something like a used car (a car that somebody bought, used for a while and now wants to sell). In other words, something that's used has been utilized or made practical use of in some form or fashion. It's actually such a basic adjective in English that it's even very difficult to define it in terms of other adjectives.

Example:

> I don't want to buy a **used** car. I want a brand-new one!

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that a really tricky business starts when you are going to negate **used to**.

Should it be:
***We used not to get up early.*** (This makes it an auxiliary, which takes the negative itself.)
***We didn’t use to get up early.*** (This makes it a lexical verb, which needs an auxiliary to precede the negative.)
***We didn’t used to get up up early.*** (Here it’s still a lexical verb, which relies on the auxiliary to take the negative but duplicates the tense marking.)

When it comes to phrasing questions with **used to**, there are the same alternatives, treating **used to** as auxiliary and as a lexical verb:
***Used you to get up early?
Did you use(d) to get up early?***

There are no clear-cut answers, but **didn’t used to** and **did you use(d) to** are prevalent in modern usage.

(From **The Cambridge Guide to English Usage**)